# An exercise in probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I've read this exercise in the internet:

"The PIRON Software Company currently develops marketing software for primarily service-based organizations. They are considering expanding their operations to product marketing in the Phoenix area. The sales representatives have contacted 500 companies, and in the past 6 months, secured contracts with 75 of those companies.

Based on the scenario above, if the sales team contacted 300 more companies in the next 90 days, what is the probability of securing a contract, and why is that the probability?"

I attempted to solve this exercise but I've not done yet. If I set $X$ = "number of secured contracts in 90 days". Based on the provided assumptions, I can not find the right distribution for $X$. Does anyone has any idea or suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: This depends highly on the process for securing a contract.  Is it instantaneous with some probability $p$, and the problem hinges on how many companies are contacted?  Or is it guaranteed upon contact, and merely takes a (variable) time period?  Or something in between?

Comment: @ vadim123: I don't know. I found this exercise here: http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/piron-software-company-currently-develops-marketing-software-primarily-service-based-organ-q5157204 , maybe it is not enough assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

It's a vague question, but here's my attempt:
For every company, there's a chance $p$ that PIRON secures a contract with one company. We can  assume that those 500 companies are a big enough sample, so $p$ is around $\frac{75}{500}=0.15$.

Now PIRON contacts another 300 companies, each with chance $0.15$ that they will secure a contract.
As you might know, if there's a chance $p$ that an event will happen, and it is tested $n$ times, the probability that the event will happen $X$ times is:
$$\binom nX \cdot p^X\cdot(1-p)^{n-X}$$
That's because of the [Binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)

Anyway, in our case $n=300,p=0.15,X=1$, so the chance of securing just one contract is:
$$\binom{300}{1} \cdot 0.15^1\cdot(1-0.15)^{300-1}$$
As we multiply $0.85$ by itself $299$ times, the answer is tiny: according to [Wolfram-Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28300+choose+1%29+%2a+0.15%5E1+%2a+%281-0.15%29%5E%28300-1%29) it's $3.5438... × 10^{-20}$

The time doesn't seem to be of any importance.

Comment: Do I have to explain the Binomial distribution, or do you understand it at Wikipedia?

Comment: @ user138676: Thank you for your answer. I understand the Binomial Distribution. However, Did you ignore the times: 6 months and 90 days. They are not important, are they?

Comment: I don't think so: anyway, it's a vague problem

Comment: Maybe this exercise appears in a Probability course and the professor of this course has some conventions that we don't khow.